# How to find out 1-to-many entry

Tags: sql, vertica

There is a data set which suppose to be 1-to-1 mapping.
For example,

```
userId, deviceId
aaa, 12345
bbb, 22398
ccc, 43284
```

However, there is a case where one deviceId has many userId.

```
userId, deviceId
ddd, 12094
eee, 12094
fff, 12094
ggg, 459834
hhh, 459834
iii, 459834
jjj, 459834
```

What SQL can list up those one-to-many entries only?
Imagine, there is a lot of one-to-many entries. I don't need 1-to-1 entry in the result. So, what I want to see as result is something like,

```
deviceId, _cnt
12094, 3
459834, 4
```

Comment: You can use `SELECT deviceId, COUNT(*) AS _cnt FROM mytable GROUP BY deviceId HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to get those `deviceId` values related with one-to-many entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you could COUNT and then filter for those that have a COUNT greater than 1:

```
SELECT deviceId
       , COUNT(DISTINCT userId) AS uct
       , COUNT(userId) AS ct
  FROM table
 GROUP BY deviceId
HAVING ct > 1 
   AND uct > 1
```

Comment: How does this query work if there are multiple 1-to-1 entries. For example, aaa, 12345, aaa, 12345, aaa, 12345.  Does it show 12345, 3?  I want to exclude those.

Comment: This query will filter all the 1-to-1 mapped entries.So it won't show the 'aaa' 
 like entries.

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference uct and ct? 
Is uct the number which excludes the one I said like 12345, 3? 
ct is including those numbers? Do I need both? Or just uct is fine?

Comment: for your example it will return 12345, 1, 3. actually it should be enough to only have utc in the query

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to use column name instead of count(*). It will improve performance as well in case of large data set.

```
SELECT deviceId, 
COUNT(userId) AS user_count
FROM table
GROUP BY deviceId
HAVING COUNT(userId)> 1
```

Comment: You can't use an alias column in a having clause.

Answer (score 1):

A simple count does it:

```
select deviceId, count(*) _cnt
from mytable
group by 1
having count(*) > 1
```

To list all entries that are not 1-1:

```
select userId, deviceId
from mytable
where deviceId in (
    select deviceId
    from mytable
    group by 1
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Or

```
select distinct a.userId, b.deviceId
from mytable a
join mytable b on b.deviceId = a.deviceId
    and b.userId != a.deviceId
```